# Custom header for a specific route

Tags: ember.js

I'm an Ember novice, still feeling my way around the framework a bit.

I'm trying to set up a custom header for a particular route (the homepage), while all other pages will use a default header. The default header is called `header`, and the homepage header is called `index-header`. Neither has any dynamic content.

The header is currently set up in `application.hbs`, like this:

```
<div class="page">
  {{view "header"}}
  ...
</div>
```

---

#### First Attempt:

My first attempt was to add an `isIndex` method to the application controller:

```
isIndex : function() {
  return this.currentRouteName === 'index';
}.property('isIndex')
```

Then in the template, I did:

```
<div class="page">
  {#if isIndex}
     {view "index-header"}
  {else}
     {view "header"}
  {/if}
  ...
</div>
```

This did not work: the template would pick the correct header initially, and then stuck with that header until a full page reload (instead of switching to/from the homepage header when navigating to/away from the homepage).

---

#### Second Attempt:

Next I tried an outlet:

```
<div class="page">
  {{outlet "header"}}
  ...
</div>
```

and in my index route:

```
renderTemplate : function() {
  this.render();
  this.render('index-header', {
    outlet : 'header',
    into : 'application',
    controller : 'application'
  });
}
```

which worked great... but then there's getting the normal header to appear everywhere else. I tried putting it in the application route's `renderTemplate` (basically the same as above, except rendering `header` instead of `index-header`), but that only runs when the application loads, so if you start on the homepage it's overwritten; if you start somewhere else, you get the right header until you reach the homepage and then you get no header at all when you leave it.

---

#### Third Attempt:

To get around the limit of the above, I figured hey, maybe I could just reset the header on leaving the index route! I gather that this is usually done by hooking on to the `willTransition` action, so I added this to my index route:

```
actions : {
  willTransition : function() {
    console.log('willtransitionning');
    this.render('header', {
      outlet : 'header',
      into : 'application',
      controller : 'application'
    });
  }
}
```

The function runs (I see the `console.log`), but it leaves the header blank.

---

So that's where I'm stuck. A possible solution is to create a subclass of `Ember.Route` with a defined `renderTemplate` function that puts the normal header in place, but this feels pretty strange. Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclassing `Ember.Route` with default app-specific behavior is totally reasonable, and how I think I would approach this problem.

I've used subclasses for things like specifying default keyboard shortcuts that can be overridden by subclasses. The way to think about it is that Ember's `Route` class provides a bunch of default behavior, and you want to add additional defaults for some group of routes. Go for it!

Incidentally, it probably makes sense for us to extend `{{outlet}}` with a mechanism to specify a default; I've seen something like this crop up a few times.